# troubles with a media query : "and ( orientation: ... )" , still appears in red in brackets

Tags: css, orientation

I am having a strange trouble in brackets.

When something is "wrong" , it's in red in the code. 
And it's the case here with something that shouldn't  : a media query i'm trying to test, to combine a responsive width for a `#wrap` element + different features whether it's in portrait or landscape on the screen.

I just can't seem to be able to simply write :

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { 
    #wrap {
            margin-top: 300px;
            margin: auto;
            width: 90%;
            font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

or :

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-width: 200px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    #wrap {
            margin-top: 300px;
            margin: auto;
            width: 90%;
            font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

It looks like this, and when I test my whole code in a Navigator it of course doesn't work :

[**Orientation problem**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcjcz.jpg)

In any case, the part "and (orientation: portrait)" is seen as a mistake . ???

I don't understand why.

I'm basically copying some bases like [**this one**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code (without line breaks):

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { 
  #wrap {
     margin-top: 300px;
     margin: auto;
     width: 90%;
     font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```